# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range on Windows

Tags: sql-server, pandas, pyodbc, numeric

I am using pyodbc to push the data from a csv file into my database. the csv file has the following structure ( showing only 2 rows)

```
      df

     vendor   FGW     prn             part      stp     stly    fact     fgy          comments
     GDAFAF  202132   TL 8+9 HHA     jkaj-98    0.12    0.999   Bhy iu   1918199  
     MAMAW   202132   TL 8+9 HHA     uysus-09   0.88    0.972   vgty22   451617
```

So I am planning to execute a sql statement using pyodbc to insert into my database.

```
    table = "Schema.Table_XXX"
      #### Connect via pyodbc 
    my_conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=MYDB;UID=jjjjjj;PWD=yyyyyy", autocommit=False)
       ### MYDB is created on Windows for ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
    my_cursor = my_conn.cursor()
    my_cursor.fast_executemany = True
    select_statement = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{0}' 
      AND TABLE_NAME = '{1}';".format(table.split('.')[0], table.split('.')[1])
      row_list = my_cursor.execute(select_statement)
      column_list = list()
      for x in row_list:
         column_list.append("[{}]".format(x[3]))  # Add all column_names in table a list
      schema_string = '(' + ', '.join(column_list) + ')'
      values_string = '(?'
      for _ in range(len(column_list) - 1):
         values_string += ', ?'
          values_string += ')'
      insert_statement = "INSERT INTO " + table + " " + schema_string + " VALUES " + values_string + ";"

      insert_params = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name='Pandas'))

      my_cursor.fast_executemany = True
  try:
      my_cursor.executemany(insert_statement, insert_params)
      my_conn.commit()  
        except pyodbc.Error as error:
         print(error)
      my_conn.rollback()
```

However, when I run this code I get an error

('22003', '[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range (0) (SQLExecute)')

The data base table I created previously was based on this

```
   CREATE TABLE [Schema].[Table_XXX](
        [vendor] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [FGW] INT NULL,
        [prn] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [part] [varchar](255) PRIMARY KEY,
        [stp] [float] NULL, 
        [stly] [float] NULL,
        [fact] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [fgy] INT NULL,
        [comments] [varchar](255) NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Not understanding how to resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `float` is rarely a good choice for storing data. Do you have a reason for this?

Comment: no I dont. Anything else is better you think will work? Thanks

Comment: The data type depends on the data. Going by your sample records, try `[stp] DECIMAL(19,17)` and `[stly] DECIMAL(19,17)` which stores xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. But it really depends on what's in your data. You might need to crack open the CSV to find the offending data. If not, you can temporarily import everything into `VARCHAR` and use `TRY_CAST` to find the offending data.

Comment: My guess would be that there is at least one [FGW] or [fgy] value that is greater than 2,147,483,647